# Javascript calculating sum of a HTML table column with For loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I have this Javascript problem I cannot solve. My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var l=liste.rows.length;    
var i;    
var den=0    
for (i=0;i<=l;i++)  
{  
den=parseInt(liste.rows[i].cells[7].innerHTML)  
den+=den  
}  
alert(den)  
</script>
```

When I put alert(den) inside the bracket code works for each step. But when I put it outside the bracket I can't have an alert box, couldn't figure out why. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Don't forget to add the radix to the parseInt, otherwise you might get weird results if your values happen to start with `0`. => `parseInt(value, 10);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overwritting den each iteration, change to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var l=liste.rows.length;
    var i;
    var den=0;
    for (i=0;i<l;i++) {
        den += parseInt(liste.rows[i].cells[7].innerHTML, 10);
    }
    alert(den);
</script>
```

**edit:** according to Tatu Ulmanen's comment I add radix to parseInt, this one drove me crazy a couple of months ago xD

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function calc()
{
var l=liste.rows.length;
var i;
var den=0
for (i=0;i<=l;i++)
{
den+=parseInt(liste.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML,10)

alert(den)
}
alert(den)
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="200" border="1" id="liste">
   <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input name="" type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calc()"/>
</body>

Comment: Thank you for your responses, but unfortunately it doesnt work. To show that it doesnt work I prepared this code above. The alert inside the for-loop bracket works and adds the numbers. But when it is outside there is no alert. You can easily try the code above and see what I mean;

Comment: the error is in the for condition (didn't noticed before) intead of `i <= l` must be `i < l` because if not, in the last iteration rows[i] is undefined and crashes... my code is updated with the correction

Answer (score 0):

You must assure first that the text is integer indeed the do the summation,

`TryParseInt` will do that for you.

```
function TryParseInt(str,defaultValue)
{     
  var retValue = defaultValue;
  if(str!=null)
  {
    if(str.length>0)
    {
       if (!isNaN(str))
       {
          retValue = parseInt(str);
       }
     }
  }     

return retValue; 
}

var den = 0;
for (var i=0; i<=liste.rows.length; i++)
{
   den += TryParseInt(liste.rows[i].cells[7].innerHTML,0);
}
alert(den);
```

[Reference](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/01/14/JavaScript-intTryParse-Equivalent.aspx)